# How-to Import CSV to disable products in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have exported a list of all my products as there are quite a few I would like to **disable**.

I notice there is a disable button in the product editor on Magento Admin. What column represents this in the CSV file?

**I would like to change this column to disable for products I would like to temporarily suspend from sale.**

Comment: Have you try with below method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just create csv file and keep below this two columns,

```
sku     product_online
test1    2
test2    2
```

product_online field in csv is used for enable and disable of product state.

**You can just set value 2 to become product disable.**

**You can just set value 1 to become product enable.**

Comment: Wah rakesh wah....!

Comment: No men , just amaze with your quick answer @Rakesh

Comment: Why they set it as 1 and 2 instead of 0 and 1.

Comment: I prefer 0 than 2.

Answer (score 1):

There is a column in CSV file called Product online, Set its value to 1 if you want product to be enabled, otherwise set its value empty.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dose it works for magento 1 as well ?